# Can I kill a creature trapped in a Tome Adept's implement?

Tags: dnd-4e, paragon-path

As I look at the Tome Adept Paragon Path found in Dragons Magazine #380. My interest is in the Daily Spell 'Librus Phantasma'.

> Daily+ Arcane, Implement, Reliable
>   Standard Action     Ranged 10
>   Req.: Tome
>   Target: One Creature
>   Attack: Intel vs Will
>   Hit: Target is trapped in your tome (save ends). Etc...

Now firstly, when I looked at this I didn't care much for it because it only seemed useful to Orb of Imposition wizards. But as I read the details more and more I realized any wizard can pick this up and kill any monster instantly (so I think).

**My question**
If you, firstly, use this spell as a standard action then use a minor action to burn the tome, will the monster die instantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It depends on your GM**

Arguments for no:

The power states:

> Hit: The target is trapped in your tome (save ends). While trapped, the target ceases to exist and can take no actions until it saves. It has line of sight and line of effect to no creature, and no creature has line of sight or line of effect to it. When the target saves, it reappears wherever it was when it was hit by this spell. If that square is occupied, it reappears in the nearest available square of the target’s choice.

The extra text is *not* an "etc." It is actually quite important. "While trapped, the target ceases to exist." Does not mean that it is locked in your tome. It simply ceases to exist. While the flavour text suggests that it is indeed embodied in the tome, there are no specific rules on harming creatures so trapped.

Furthermore, the first line states "trapped in your tome" which suggests that if you destroy you tome, you destroy the prison.

Finally, destroying your primary implement to kill one creature represents a huge resource expenditure, as you're only expected to get one implement every 5 levels. It is not an intelligent act to perform this destruction. Which would only be possible with, as far as I can tell, the "disenchant magic item" ritual.

Arguments for yes:

It's awfully cool. Assuming that you can extend the dungeon enchanter feat:

> Benefit: You can use the Enchant Magic Item and Transfer Enchantment rituals with a casting time of 1 minute.

To disenchanting magic items, it would make for a fantastic MacGuffin to bind the enemy into a book and disenchant the book. The rest of the party can try to contain it, perhaps jumping into a specially prepared book to do battle and penalize its saving throws.

If you're prepared to sacrifice a tome of equal level to the monster to destroy it, with the realization that you're *not* getting another one... go for it. Clearly the fight means a lot to you.

It's kinda awesome, especially if you've prepared a way to destroy it and confine the soul inside while its being destroyed (which simply burning wouldn't do).

If you want to do this, talk with your GM and inform him of your plans and ask him to work it into the story.

Answer (score 1):

You can rule that destroying the tome (if it's possible, see GMNoob's answer) would end the effect of the spell and therefore free the monster, since I don't think the tome's life is connected to that of the monster but to that of the spell effect (although it's hard to tell without knowing the exact spell details).

I don't think this spell is intended to instantly kill the monster, since it was one the corner design revisions of the 4th edition to remove Instant Death effects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

Just because you are able to ignite the tome instantly, does not mean that the tome goes up in flames instantly.  You would likely have to roll fire damage to see how damaged the book gets each round, while in combat.

Secondly, if you were able to find a way to completely destroy the tome with a minor action,(like tossing it into a black hole) you would be out a tome.  I'd have to look up the rules more completely on tomes, but I imagine they aren't something which you can easily replace.

Also, I would not be surprised to find a rule somewhere which suggests that tomes are indestructible.